# How to check if any row is selected from GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rowdatabound

I have a gridview in aspx page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdvMainList" runat="server" CssClass="Grid1" SkinID="PagedGridView"
                                    AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gdvMainList_RowDataBound"
                                    DataSourceId="dtsConsumers" Visible="false" DataKeyNames="Id">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:CommandField SelectText="Select" ShowSelectButton="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="HideButton"
                                            HeaderStyle-CssClass="HideButton">
                                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="HideButton" />
                                            <ItemStyle CssClass="HideButton" />
                                        </asp:CommandField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <span>
                                                    <%# Pc.PrecisionCare2.PL.Common.Utility.GetFullName("", Eval("LastName"), Eval("FirstName"), Eval("MiddleInit")) %></span>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <ItemStyle Width="200px" />
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status"></asp:BoundField>
                                    </Columns>
                                    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="SelectedItem" BackColor="#c9e0ee" />
                                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                        <div class="divEmptyGrid">
                                            --- No Consumer Exists ---
                                        </div>
                                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                </asp:GridView>
```

The `rowDataBound` Method is:

```
protected void gdvMainList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.gdvMainList, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
            }
        }
```

I have an OK button, when it is clicked, I collect data from page. I want to check on OK button click that is there any row selected from Gridview or not.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can check like...

```
if (GridView1.SelectedValue != null)
{
     //Row is Selected
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
If GridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
' yourcode here - a row is selected 
Else
' yourcode here - NO row is selected 
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Better this:

```
if(GridView1.SelectedIndex < 0)
    { its -1 and no row is selected.}
else
    {its >= 0 and a row is selected}
```

testing for `!= null` will throw an exception if the selected value is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

you can also check like this

```
if(GridView.SelectedIndex >= 0)
   {
      string result = "Selected";
   }
    else
   {
     string result = "Not Selected";
   }
```